# Antd Cascader not show children when applied data fetched from api with SWR

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am trying to use Ant Design Cascader component but this has occurred a problem when i applied data fetched from API with SWR Hook.

My code:

```
  const { dataCategories: { data }} = useCategories(); //SWR custom hook to reusable in another components

/*
 I got the result after fetched:

 [
  {
    cate_id: 1,
    cate_name: 'Apple',
    has_children: true,
    ...
  },
  {
    cate_id: 2,
    cate_name: 'Asus',
    has_children: true,
    ...
  },
  {
    cate_id: 3,
    cate_name: 'Dell',
    has_children: true,
    ...
  }
]*/

  const [options, setOptions] = useState(data);

  const loadData = async selectedOptions => {

    const targetOption = selectedOptions[selectedOptions.length - 1];
    targetOption.loading = true;    
    setTimeout(() => {
      targetOption.loading = false;
      targetOption.children = [
        {
          cate_name: 'iPhone',
          cate_id: 1,
          has_children: false,
        },
        {
          cate_name: 'Macbook',
          cate_id: 2,
          has_children: false,
        }       
      ];
      setOptions([...options]);
    }, 2000);        

  };


return (

<Cascader 
  fieldNames={{ label: 'cate_name', value: 'cate_id' }}
  options={options.map(e => ({ ...e, isLeaf: !e.has_children }) )}
  loadData={loadData}
  changeOnSelect 
  placeholder="Please select your category" 
/>        

)
```

Currently, it's showing items, but when i clicked to each item to open children cascader it's always spinning and not response.
What i am wrong?

Comment: You initialize `targetOption` in `loadData` function and in the end of function put options inside the state!!!?

Comment: @davoodSandoghsaz  yep, i am doing following the official documentation from Antd

Comment: Where I am wrong?

Comment: It's not correct. You must use this:  `setOptions([...targetOption]);` instead of `setOptions([...options]);`

Comment: @davoodSandoghsaz  it's still not working, always showing icon spinning

Comment: I think when you has `loadData` attribute doesn't need to `options` attribute